# Sitecore: Sitemap generation and performance issues, alternatives

Tags: sitecore, sitemap, sitecore6

I was having a look at the available Sitemap module in Sitecore marketplace and seems like it's using something along the line of

```
[Pseudocode and several lines combined]
var items = database.Items[Factory.GetSite(siteName).rootpath].Axes.GetDescendants();
```

then filter expected items by template id and exclude unexpected items by item id.

I was just wondering.. isn't this root.Descendants stuff exponentially taxing on performance? New to Sitecore so please shed some light. Also, if I just wana get all items (satisfying certain conditions such as published and most importantly, probably based on a master template or something..i.e. I am looking for a way where I won't have to select template like that cause if I implement my own version which doesn't have a GUI (e.g. a generic handler) then of course mapping out ID is gonna be quite ugly) then is there a better way of doing it? (pretty confident there is one!)

Comment: Potentially a performance hit depending on number of items, but only a one time hit if you cache the sitemap. If you index your items then you could create it yourself from Lucene.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion re Lucene. I need to check whether or not it's indexed. If not then probably that's what we need to do first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Item.Axes.GetDescendants() could indeed be a potential performance penalty, however, Sitecore uses a so called Item cache, which caches the items that are read from the database. So the first hit could take some time, but the second hit could read the items from the Item cache and you can cache your Sublayout or rendering also.

However, I would make some changes and would use the `StartPath` instead of the RootPath to only include items below the homepage, because the StartPath is your homepage and RootPath is a parent item.
I would also add a checkbox-field "IncludeInSitemap" to a base template for the content items and use LINQ to filter the items on this checked field.

```
var items = Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem(Sitecore.Context.Site.StartItem)
 .Axes.GetDescendants()
 .Where(item => item.Fields["IncludeInSitemap"].Value.Equals("1"));
```

Of course you need to add some extra null-reference checks but you get the idea.

Comment: Darn cool I was indeed thinking of this check box solution as well! Cool thanks I am gonna try that out today.